# Finding the row number in an array with specific values

Tags: matlab

let say i have an array 
a = [1 2;
    3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10];

I want to find row number which has the following elements [7 8]. Answer would be row 4. How do i do that in matlab

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function for this purpose:

```
[~,ind] = ismember([7,8],a,'rows')
```

Result:

```
ind = 4
```